# soup.find_all находит не все классы

Tags: requests, beautiful-soup

Использую Суп soup.find_all("div", class_="ticket-title") в DOM дереве наблюдаю как минимум 20 нужных мне классов.Но Суп упорно отбирает только 10.Почему?
К XPath привязаться не могу они разные все 20 штук

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывел принт чтоб посмотреть сколько там

```
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
links_product = soup.find_all("div", class_="ticket-title")
```

Оказалось 12.Из которых 10 ссылок всего а не 20.
requests.get возвращает пол страницы?

В супе нашел вот такой кусок текста

window.server.ids = ["34552076","34542522","34537520","34549891","34481540","34464862","33906513","34551692","34404547","34543366"];
Тут реально 10 айдишек.а где же остальные 10?

При том что в DOM дереве эта же строка содержит 20 айдишек.

window.server.ids = ["34552076","34542522","34537520","34549891","34481540","34464862","33906513","34551692","34404547","34543366","34355769","34416508","34338705","34532822","1899088","1899121","34333066","34423115","34538403","34545649"];

Может сайт защищен от парсинга?

Comment: Что просите, то и выдает.

Comment: я прошу отдать 20 ссылок.которые есть в дум дереве.а риквест возвращает 10,то есть пол страницы.Что там можно просить?Если открывая полную ссылку которую я ему скармливаю  я вижу на ней 20 объявлений(ссылок которые мне нужны).Если бы ссылка не верная то вообще ничего бы не вернул!

Comment: requests не браузер. Не мучайтесь испрользуйте селенимум. Не возможно конкретно ответить на ваш вопрос по вашим скудным данным.

Comment: я селениум тоже использую.вопрос решен.Все дело в урле было.Он меняется.Есть краткий урл по нему риквест 10 обьяв находит а есть другой урл более длинны.он мне вернул 20 ссылок